# area bounded by two curves using double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Need to find the area enclosed by two parabolas x=y^2 and x=2y-y^2.
I do know how to plot them but what do you exactly integrate after you find your bounds?

Comment: You integrate the function $z = 1$ because area of a prism will be same as volume when height = 1 : $$A = \iint_R 1 dA$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer generally, as you have said that you found the bounds.  Let's say you have two functions, $x=f(y)$ and $x=g(y)$, which intersect at $y=y_1$ and $y=y_2$, with $y_1\lt y_2$.  Also assume that between the bounds, $f(y)\le g(y)$.  Then you may write the integral as

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2} dy \, \int_{f(y)}^{g(y)} dx $$

Comment: OK I got the answer now. just curious, in this case could it have been like your y1 and y2 be x1 and x2 and you g and f would be in terms of x? if you didn't understand what I just said, just say and ill write it clearer.

Comment: @snowman: I understand, and yes, that would be correct.